# How can I write $n!$ using $\sum$?

Tags: summation, notation, factorial

How can I write $n!$ using $\sum$?

Should I write $\sum\limits_{k=2}^n k$?

The domain is $n>1$

Comment: do you know what $n!$ means?

Comment: Maybe $n! = \exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \log k \right)$

Comment: @JustDroppedIn It's the factorial

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $\Pi$ for product?

Comment: May be $$n!=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(n-1)!$$

Comment: You can also do it by partitioning the permutation count in terms of number of fixed points.

Comment: $$n! = \sum_{k=1}^n\left[n\atop k\right]$$

Answer (score 7):

Note that for non-negative integer $n$,
$$
n! = 1 \times 2 \times \ldots \times n = \prod_{k=1}^n k.
$$
If you want to write $n!$ using a sum-like expression, note that
$$
\ln(n!) = \ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^n k \right)
        = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln k,
$$
so
$$
n! = \exp\left(\sum_{k=1}^n \ln k\right),
$$
but not sure this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

$n!$ involves the multiplication of subsequent terms, rather than an addition, and therefore it is a ***product*** rather than a ***sum***. 
Therefore, we would typically use product notation, signified by $\prod$ as opposed to $\sum$.

The best expression is 
$$\prod_{k=1}^{n}{k}$$